# Can i embed google calendar on my website so users can log in/ see their own calender

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

As the title states I want to embed the Google calendar on my website. But the tricky part is that I want that the users who visit the website are able to "log in" and see their own google calendar.
What I have right now is that I can show my personal calendar on the website but that's not what I want.
Is my question possible?

What I have right now is that I can show my personal calendar on the website but that's not what I want. I'll include the code, but it's not the right API.

```
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
}
```

I want to put the entire Google calendar app on my website but I can only show a specific users calendar with this code.

Comment: [Integrating Google Sign In into your WebApp](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

Comment: But will users be able to sign in and see their calendar on my website?

Comment: Hey @azem were you able to solve your issue with my answer? Kindly let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Get the user's events by using the API, and rendering them in your website as you please. You can follow the Google Calendar API [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js) to understand how that works. You can also use libraries such as [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar).
2. Using a Google Calendar [embed](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en). For that, you will need the user to be already logged into his google account, and to get his gmail in order to create the embed URL.